# Find $\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb{N}} B_k$ if $B_k=\left\{k-1,k,k+1\right\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is not a homework problem. I want to find 
\begin{align}
\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb{N}} B_k,\tag{1}
\end{align}
if $B_k=\left\{k-1,k,k+1\right\}$. I know these sets are not pair-wise disjoint, but the total set does not intersect. For instance, I know that
\begin{align}
\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}}B_k=\mathbb{N}\cup\left\{-1\right\},\tag{2}
\end{align}
but what about $\left(1\right)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $k$ and $k+3$, then $B_k=\{k-1,k,k+1\}$ and $B_{k+3}=\{k+2,k+3,k+4\}$ which are disjoint.  Therefore, the intersection is empty.

Comment: Then this implies, it seems, $\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb{N}}B_k=\emptyset$?

Comment: What if, then, I simply wanted to investigate whether or not this collection of sets were pairwise-disjoint or not, instead of whether the total collection intersected?

Comment: @jm324354 $\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb N} B_k \subseteq B_{1} \cap B_4 = \emptyset$.

Comment: @jm324354 Two sets $B_i$ and $B_j$ are disjoint if and only if $|i-j|\geq 3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha\in \bigcap_{k\in\mathbb{N}} B_k$. Then $\alpha\in B_k$ for every $k\in \mathbb N$. So $$k-1\le\alpha\le k+1$$ for all $k\in \mathbb N$. It follows that for every $k\in \mathbb N$$$k\le \alpha +1 $$ which is a contradiction.